# Making variables immutable in R

Tags: r

If I try to set `NA` or another special variable in R I get a nice warning:

```
> NA <- 1
```

> Error in NA <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

Is it possible to achieve the same with variables defined in my own code?

I tried to use `lockBinding('foo', parent.env(environment())` inside my package `.onLoad()` but that will happily allow me to shadow the locked binding.

### To expand:

In a package `myPackage` I can create the following `init.R` file:

```
#' @export
foo <- 1

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  lockBinding('foo', parent.env(environment()))
}
```

`devtools::document()` and `R CMD INSTALL` it and now do:

```
> library(myPackage)
> foo
[1] 1
> foo <- 2
> foo
[1] 2
> myPackage::foo
[1] 1
> rm(foo)
> foo
[1] 1
```

I want to make it so that `foo` doesn't get shadowed (like `NA` can't be).

Comment: We can use `backquotes`, but not recommended to use reserved words  to name object identifiers

Comment: I'm looking to mimic the behavior of `NA` not use it anywhere.

Comment: This is in fact possible.`foo` needs to be an active binding that triggers a function returning a constant, while `foo <- value` will trigger a function which fails. My package {typed} offers a simple way to do this, you define ` ? (foo) <- value` and foo will be constant. However what you want is to define `foo` in a package, and active binding in packages are not easy to do, though possible too. I'll try to come back here to post a complete answer because it is a great question, but in case I don't I hope this can give pointers to the bravest users.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I forgot why I wanted this but I’m looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s no way to get the same effect as with reserved names. A reserved name simply cannot be shadowed (you can assign to `` `NA` `` but it never shadows `NA` — evaluating `NA` simply never performs a variable lookup). Whereas variables always can.

Incidentally, your `lockBinding` call in `.onLoad` is redundant: Bindings for package symbols are locked by default.

Comment: That's too bad but as noone chimed I'm going to invoke Cunningham's Law.

Answer (score 6):

You could override `<-`, this would be a very bad idea in general if done in the global environment, but done in a specific environement if you know what you're doing why not :

```r
X <- new.env()
X$`<-` <- function(e1, e2) {
  sc <- sys.call()
  if(identical(sc[[2]], quote(foo)))
     stop("invalid left-hand side to assignment")
  else
    eval.parent(do.call(substitute, list(sc, list(`<-` = base::`<-`))))
}

with(X, foo <- 42)
#> Error in foo <- 42: invalid left-hand side to assignment
with(X, bar <- 42)
X$bar
#> [1] 42
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is brilliant and I've upvoted it but I'm not going to use it ;)